# ConfigurationManager throw Null Exception

Tags: c#, appdomain, configurationmanager

I face one issue when I tried to get something for my app.config.

So my code is simple:

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap()
{
    ExeConfigFilename = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile,
};

Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
string value = config.AppSettings.Settings["test"].Value; // this is working
string value2 = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["test"]; // throw an exception
```

The only tricky stuff here is the way of my code is loaded.
An C++ exe load my C# Assembly in an AppDomain and call my code.

I have this kind of file structure

- Application.exe (C++)
- myDll.dll.config
- myDll.dll

The problem is some library like NLog for example call `ConfigurationManager.GetSection()` and this block the init of the logger.

So do you have any idea arround this ?

Thanks in advance for your help ;)

Extra Info:

- Net 4.7.2
- Windows 10

Comment: Where are your settings - in the myDll.dll.config?

Comment: Are you asumming that opening and external .config file does store its config in the application actual configuration settings?

Comment: @st_stefanov: Yes my settings are inside `myDll.dll.config`. @Cleptus: Not really. For me `ConfigurationManager.GetSection()` will search inside the configuration file referenced by the current domain. it's not like that ?